# Why does the "next" not work here? I used the next key word to move on to the next word iteration but it seems to upcase all the characters

Tags: ruby, iteration

```
def wave(str)
  return [] if str.empty?
  str_size = str.size
  final_arr = []
  str_size.times do
    final_arr << str
  end

  counter = 0
  final_arr.each do |word|
    if word[counter] =~ /[a-z]/
      word[counter] = word[counter].upcase
      counter += 1
      next
    elsif word[counter] == " "
      counter += 1
      next
    end
  end

  final_arr
end
p wave("hello") == ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]
```

My code outputs ["HELLO", "HELLO", "HELLO", "HELLO", "HELLO"] instead of ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]. I don't know why this is happening someone please help

Answer (score 2):

It's because here

```
  str_size.times do
    final_arr << str
  end
```

You push *the same string* into the array multiple times.

Since the array contains the *same string* multiple times, changing the string in any one place changes *all occurrences*.

You can reproduce the same behavior like this:

```
str = "foo"
arr = 3.times.map { str }
arr # => ["foo", "foo", "foo"]

str[0] = "F"
arr # => ["Foo", "Foo", "Foo"]
```

To solve this, just clone the string when you push it into the array:

```
str_size.times do
  final_arr << str.clone
end
```

Comment: Yes is like he says, it has the same reference, so the object_id is the same for every string in your array, clone the string prevent that.

Comment: Don't worry @Nnamdi this is a pretty tricky aspect of programming, you can read here for more info https://launchschool.medium.com/variable-references-and-mutability-of-ruby-objects-4046bd5b6717

Answer (score 2):

You're not putting 5 copies of the string "hello" into the final array. You're putting the same string "hello" into the array 5 times.

You're then modifying the same one string. First upcasing the H, then upcasing the E and so on until the whole "hello" is "HELLO".

```
str = 'hello'
final_arr = []
str.size.times do
  final_arr << str
end
puts final_arr.inspect #=> ["hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello"]
str[0] = '0'
puts final_arr.inspect #=> ["0ello", "0ello", "0ello", "0ello", "0ello"]
final_arr[0][1] = '1'
puts final_arr.inspect #=> ["01llo", "01llo", "01llo", "01llo", "01llo"]
```

If you want to add 5 copies of the string into the array, call `.dup` on the string to make a copy.

```
str = 'hello'
final_arr = []
str.size.times do
  final_arr << str.dup
end
puts final_arr.inspect #=> ["hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello"]
str[0] = '0'
puts final_arr.inspect #=> ["hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello"]
final_arr[0][1] = '1'
puts final_arr.inspect #=> ["h1llo", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello"]
```